# How to personalize the django admin templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm developing a Web App in Django, and I plan to make a heavy use of the admin module.

I modified the templates that are in the directory `django/contrib/admin/templates` but this method affects all the projects that use the admin module.

I need  to know how can I personalize the templates of the admin module without affect other projects that use the same module.

Comment: [Custom template options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach to modify the admin templates is create a copy of the templates inside your project.

1. Create a directory `templates` inside your project.
2. Copy the templates from `django/contrib/admin/templates/` to your
   `templates` directory.
3. Add the path of your `templates` directory to the `settings.py`

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( 
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'templates),
)
```

Now you can modify to the admin templates without affect other dependent projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the `collectstatic` command for the particular project you should be able to change the admin templates that are copied to the static directory you have specified in your project settings.